# Применение функциональных интерфейсов для Stratery pattern

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть мапер на mapstruct который в зависимости от типа тикета вызывает разные map методы и все это реализовано через if else условия. Пытаюсь переписать это на Strategy pattern или что-то похожее на него, но в данном контексте все время что-то не сходится.

```
// Хотелось бы как-то на месте инициализировать список условий
Map<Set<TicketType>, Function<TicketRequestDto, Ticket>> ticketMapStrategies = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(
    ... Как-то наполнить на месте, но как? ...
);


default Ticket ticketRequestDtoToTicket(TicketRequestDto dto) {
    TicketType type = dto.getType();

    if (type.equals(TicketType.EMERGENCY_STOP) || type.equals(TicketType.SETTING_UPLOAD)
            || dto.getType().equals(TicketType.SETTING_DOWNLOAD)) {
        return ticketEmergencyStopRequestDtoToTicket(dto);
    } else if (type.equals(TicketType.DEPOSIT_INCOME) || type.equals(TicketType.DEPOSIT_OUTCOME)) {
        return ticketAccountTransferRequestDtoToTicket(dto);
    } else if (type.equals(TicketType.PARTNER_REQUEST)) {
        return ticketPartnershipRequestDtoToTicket(dto);
    } else {
        return ticketInfoRequestDtoToTicket(dto);
    }
}

@Mapping(target = "instance.id", source = "instanceId")
@Mapping(target = "recipient.id", source = "recipientId")
Ticket ticketEmergencyStopRequestDtoToTicket(TicketRequestDto dto);

@Mapping(target = "account.id", source = "accountId")
@Mapping(target = "recipient.id", source = "recipientId")
Ticket ticketAccountTransferRequestDtoToTicket(TicketRequestDto dto);

@Mapping(target = "sender.id", source = "senderId")
@Mapping(target = "recipient.id", source = "recipientId")
Ticket ticketPartnershipRequestDtoToTicket(TicketRequestDto dto); 

Ticket ticketInfoRequestDtoToTicket(TicketRequestDto dto);
```

Хотелось бы как-то на месте инициализировать список условий а в `ticketRequestDtoToTicket` просто доставать по ключу. Что-то вроде:

```
    Set<TicketType> key = ticketMapStrategies.keySet().stream()
            .filter(set -> set.contains(dto.getType()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(new HashSet<>());
    return ticketMapStrategies.get(key).apply(dto);
```

Или что-то покомпактнее если возможно.

Ну или что-то в таком духе. Как это можно реализовать учитывая что все это происходит в интерфейсе?

**Java 11**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока самый приемлимый вариант который удалось найти, - это использовать `@PostConstruct` и в нем заполнять мапу.

```
Map<Set<TicketType>, Function<TicketRequestDto, Ticket>> ticketMapStrategies = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@PostConstruct
default void init() {
    ticketMapStrategies.put(
            Set.of(TicketType.INFO),
            this::ticketInfoRequestDtoToTicket);
    ticketMapStrategies.put(
            Set.of(TicketType.PARTNER_REQUEST),
            this::ticketPartnershipRequestDtoToTicket);
    ticketMapStrategies.put(
            Set.of(TicketType.DEPOSIT_INCOME, TicketType.DEPOSIT_OUTCOME),
            this::ticketAccountTransferRequestDtoToTicket);
    ticketMapStrategies.put(
            Set.of(TicketType.EMERGENCY_STOP, TicketType.SETTING_UPLOAD, TicketType.SETTING_DOWNLOAD),
            this::ticketEmergencyStopRequestDtoToTicket);
}

default Ticket ticketRequestDtoToTicket(TicketRequestDto dto) {
    Set<TicketType> key = ticketMapStrategies.keySet().stream()
            .filter(set -> set.contains(dto.getType())).findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(UnsupportedTicketTypeException::new);
    return ticketMapStrategies.get(key).apply(dto);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

как пор мне, `ConcurrentHashMap` вам не нужна - у вас же не происходит добавление в мапу в нескольких потоках.

Можно примерно так (если java11+)

```
Map<Set<TicketType>, Function<TicketRequestDto, Ticket>> map = Map.of(
    Set.of(TicketType.EMERGENCY_STOP, TicketType.SETTING_UPLOAD, TicketType.SETTING_DOWNLOAD), this::ticketEmergencyStopRequestDtoToTicket,
    Set.of(TicketType.DEPOSIT_INCOME, TicketType.DEPOSIT_OUTCOME), this::ticketAccountTransferRequestDtoToTicket,
    Set.of(TicketType.PARTNER_REQUEST), this::ticketPartnershipRequestDtoToTicket
);

default Ticket ticketRequestDtoToTicket(TicketRequestDto dto) {
    return map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains(dto.getType))
       .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
       .findFirst()
       .orElseGet(this::ticketInfoRequestDtoToTicket)
       .apply(dto);
}
```

Если же у вас java8, то можно проинциализировать на месте

```
Map<Set<TicketType>, Function<TicketRequestDto, Ticket>> map = new HashMap() {{
    map.put(new HashSet(Arrays.asList(перечислить нужные типы тикета)), this::ticketEmergencyStopRequestDtoToTicket);
    //вставить все остальные подобным способом.
}}
```

Если в проект подключена либа guava, то там можно воспользовать [ImmutableMap](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html):

```
Map<Set<TicketType>, Function<TicketRequestDto, Ticket>> map = ImmutableMap.of(
    new HashSet(Arrays.asList(перечислить нужные типы тикета)), this::ticketEmergencyStopRequestDtoToTicket),
    // добавить все остальное
);
```

**P.S.**
Вообще, тут по сути мапа как структура не нужна - мы ни разу не вызываем метод `.get()` у мапы => мапа как структура тут не нужна. Ее спокойно можно заменить на лист пар (`List<Pair<Set<TicketType>, Function<TicketRequestDto, Ticket>>>`)

Comment: как тогда будет выглядеть вариант для `List<Pair<Set<TicketType>, Function<TicketRequestDto, Ticket>>>`?  У меня `get()` вызывается `ticketMapStrategies.get(key).apply(dto)`.

Comment: И мне нужен потокобезопасный  вариант

Comment: @Pavel если нужна `concurrentHashMap`, то можно сделать `new ConcurrentHashMap<>(Map.of(...));`

Comment: в интерфейсе у меня нету `this` а если использовать `TicketMapper::ticketEmergencyStopRequestDtoToTicket` то `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context` потому что методы не статические а `default` этого требует mapstruct а одновременно и default и static быть не может. 'pro.laplacelab.controller.mappers.TicketMapper.this' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: @Pavel хороший поинт. пока сходу могу только предложить костыль - это сделать приватный метод, который будет возвращать вашу мапу. типо такого
```
private Map<String, Function<String, Object>> getMap() { 
            return Map.of(
                    Set.of(TicketType.PARTNER_REQUEST), this::ticketPartnershipRequestDtoToTicket
            );
        }
``` и в методе `ticketRequestDtoToTicket` уже использовать `getMap()` вместо `map`. Но я думаю это не ваш случай

Comment: в итоге все закончилось `@PostConstruct` с заполнением этой мапы)))